# Use jQuery load method to grab injected element

Tags: jquery, load

I am using the jQuery load method to fetch a select box that contains size options from a Product Details page, back to a Product Listing page. It's very standard, like this:

```
<select class="validation">
<option value="" selected="selected">-- Please Choose an Option --</option>
<option value="Small">Small</option>
<option value="Medium">Medium</option>
<option value="Large">Large</option>
<option value="X-Large">X-Large</option>
</select>
```

I inject it and then loop over it, using those sizes to generate a size filter - all of which is working fine. The first part of this code is where I grab it.

```
    $(prodItems).each(function (i) {

    var prodLI = $(this),
        getSelect = $(prodLI).find("a").attr("href") + " div.productOptionViewSelect select",
        currentProd = $(prodLI).find("div.ProductImage").attr("data-product");

    $(prodLI).append($("<div id='sizes' style='display: none'>").load(getSelect, function () {
        appendSizes(prodLI, currentProd);
        appendCount++;

        // Sizes built, so load filters
        if (count == appendCount) {
            // call filter function
        }
    }));
});
```

HOWEVER, I've since realised that there's also some JavaScript on the product page (that I don't have access to) that works out which of these are in stock and then regenerates a new select tag which it injects immediately before this one, setting the original tag to display:none.

My question: How can I grab this new, injected, select tag. I literally have the whole solution working, bar this..I fear I may need some pro advice here, or a shoulder to cry on. I don't suppose this is gunna be an easy one? :-/

Comment: All right , what you have tried?

Comment: Show us your full code or making an online demo would be more easy to understand your problem. Also what is `prodItems` in your code?

Comment: @sudhar this is not super easy and apparently OP is fighting with JS execution order - he/she did provide the code and enough information.

Comment: The first thing to say is I have absolutely no access to the select box, so I cannot resolve this by appending an attribute to the options based on stock. I have also noted that if I try and target the select box (by select:first, select:visible or some other based on the altered DOM) I cannot. I presume this is because I am not included the JavaScript that is responsible for producing it? Obviously I can’t adjust this to load the entire page. And I doubt I can create a custom streamlined version of the product details page where I may be able to do this, again due to restrictions.

Comment: prodItems is all the products on a listing page. I iterate over each, fetching back the sizes of each product.

Answer (score 0):

So something is adding an element BEFORE the element YOU are creating? If you have access to the one you create, you could use `.prev()`

https://api.jquery.com/prev/

In your case it would be:

```
$('.validation').prev()
```

**UPDATE**

Another alternative: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_delegate.asp

Comment: I am not creating an element. I am trying to fetch an element, which is then being hidden and a new element placed before it in the DOM with some JS I have not written myself. I cannot use this unfortunately as, at this stage, the injected item does not exist.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_delegate.asp) is what you're looking for then ?

Comment: Thanks Jamie. How would I use delegate with load (and append) please?